# Dual table issue

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hi We all know `DUAL` is the table of `SYS` and other users have synonym of it.
but when i fire the below commnad

```
 create table dual(x varchar2(1));
```

it worked. An object of the name `DUAL` was created.

when there is already a synonym with the name `DUAL` how can we create another object of same name? why oracle is allowing us to do it.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a table named `DUAL` because tables and **public** synonyms have a different namespace. For details, see chapter [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) of Oracle's SQL Language Reference.

EDIT: To illustrate the mechanism:

If you create your own `DUAL` table as user scott

```
CREATE TABLE dual (x VARCHAR2(1));
```

... then it shows up in the data dictionary:

```
SELECT object_id, object_type, owner, object_name, namespace 
  FROM dba_objects 
 WHERE object_name='DUAL';

OBJECT_ID OBJECT_TYPE OWNER  OBJECT_NAME NAMESPACE
      142 TABLE       SYS    DUAL                1
      143 SYNONYM     PUBLIC DUAL                1
    78138 TABLE       SCOTT  DUAL                1
```

So, the names are unique per owner **and** namespace. You cannot add yet another table in your schema called DUAL. You cannot create a private synonym named DUAL, but you can create your own synonym for schemas in other objects.

Please make sure to drop the table again. Even simple statements won't work anymore:

```
SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL;
--


DROP TABLE dual;
SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL;
01.07.2018
```

Comment: *'You cannot add a second table called DUAL.'* But surely he just did? You just cannot create it in the `SYS` schema.

Comment: I mean another table in his schema, in addition to his first one.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth making that clarification in the answer, to avoid any confusion :)

Comment: Done, better so?

Answer (score 1):

I think `DUAL` is a distraction here. Of course it's a system table and there are side effects if you mess about with it, so don't. But the question is really about why there is no namespace conflict between *any* object and a public synonym with the same name. For example, I can create a table named `ALL_TABLES` or `DBMS_OUTPUT` in my own schema (if I really want to). Or, I can create a table called `MYDEMOTABLE` and then create a public synonym `MYDEMOTABLE` for `WILLIAM.MYDEMOTABLE`.

But then, what restriction are you expecting to exist? There is already both a table (owned by `SYS`) and a public synonym (owned by `PUBLIC`) named `DUAL`. You can create a third object with the same name, as long as it isn't owned by `SYS` or `PUBLIC`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way to demonstrate what is going on (without using `DUAL` or any other `SYS` object ;-):

If two users create a table with the same name, the tables end up in their own schema as expected:

```
CREATE USER user_a IDENTIFIED BY user_a;
CREATE USER user_b IDENTIFIED BY user_b;

CREATE TABLE user_a.foo (x NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE user_b.foo (x NUMBER);

SELECT object_id, object_type, owner, object_name, namespace 
  FROM dba_objects 
 WHERE object_name='FOO';

OBJECT_ID OBJECT_TYPE OWNER   OBJECT_NAME NAMESPACE
    78225 TABLE       USER_A  FOO                 1
    78226 TABLE       USER_B  FOO                 1
```

But when one of them creates a public synonym (as `SYS` did with it's `DUAL` table), it ends up in a magic schema with the name `PUBLIC`:

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM foo FOR user_a.foo;

SELECT object_id, object_type, owner, object_name, namespace 
  FROM dba_objects 
 WHERE object_name='FOO';

OBJECT_ID OBJECT_TYPE OWNER   OBJECT_NAME NAMESPACE
    78225 TABLE       USER_A  FOO                 1
    78226 TABLE       USER_B  FOO                 1
    78156 SYNONYM     PUBLIC  FOO                 1
```

So, in other words, public synonyms are just synonyms that live in the schema `PUBLIC`. And you can have only one table, view, sequence, package, synonym with the same name per schema.

Answer (score 0):

There have various schemas in your single database. When you asked about default `DUAL` table, which actually belongs to `'sys' Schema` which is system schema. But your default Database schema is `dbo` it means when you have executed your query to create DUAL table is actually created in your default schema named `dbo`.

---

If you want to check their actual double existence there are many ways to check.

- You can apply a query like `"select * from sys.DUAL"` and `"select * from dbo.DUAL"`. there you will see two different outputs.
- you can check all the schemas in `"select * from sys.schemas"`.
- Also, you can check their different schemas in with table name

  > `"select * from sys.tables where name ='DUAL'";`
  >   the result will be two different tables with two different schema Id's.

Hope this will help you to understand schema basics.

Comment: This doesn't look like Oracle.

Comment: @irfan_m you are mostly right, in that the OP has clearly created a table named `DIAL` in his own schema and not in the `SYS` schema. However in Oracle there is no `DBO` schema by default, and there is no `sys.schemas` or `sys.tables`.

Comment: yes, sorry guys. Actually, I have never worked in Oracle but I thought Oracle also same as SQL server. So I gave my solution related SQL server

Comment: Interesting that so much is similar though. I guess schemas are implemented slightly differently, and Oracle has `dba_users` instead of `sys.schemas` etc, but basically it's still true that you can reuse the same table name in different schemas.